# Is there a better/more efficient way to do this (vectorised)? Very slow performance with Pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

So in R, I'd use an optimized apply function for this, but I've read now that the Panda's apply function is an abstracted loop and is perhaps even slower than one, and it shows in the performance. On my machine, it took 30 mins to process 60k rows.

So essentially I'm looking to calculate a moving average based on a dataset with different groups on which I need to calculate a moving average. There are a lot of these groups. So I essentially first have to subset the dataset on a row/cell-wise basis, and only then calculate the moving average.

So I'm trying to come up with a vectorised solution to this but can't seem to figure how you'd go about subsetting the dataframe within a vectorised approach.

My current solution makes use of an apply function which is really easy to understand and maintain:

```
df['SMA'] = df.apply(SMA, axis=1)

def SMA(row):
     Subset = df[(df['group']==row['group'])&(df['t']<=row['t'])].reset_index()
     Subset2 = Subset[len(Subset.index)-(2):len(Subset.index)]
     return df['val'].mean()
```

This is my expected output (which I am currently getting but just very very slowly):

This is the dataframe and this example I want the moving average over two timepoints, "t" in this example:

```
t   group   val moving average
1   A        1  NA
2   A        2  1.5
3   A        3  2.5
1   B        4  NA
2   B        5  4.5
3   B        6  5.5
1   C        7  NA
2   C        8  7.5
3   C        9  8.5
```

Comment: can you post the output you are getting and expected output?

Comment: output was included, but edited for clarity :)

Comment: @Topographical `apply` in pandas is notoriously slow and must be used as very last resource. As you are returning one value per group, this might probably be achieved with `agg` rather than `apply`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of operation (splitting into groups) is handled by the `.groupby` method in pandas. If we take care to set the index to time, it also handles giving us the right output with a time index back.

Here's an example which does basically the same as your code:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(
   [[1, 'A', 1], 
    [2, 'A', 2], 
    [3, 'A', 3], 
    [1, 'B', 4], 
    [2, 'B', 5], 
    [3, 'B', 6], 
    [1, 'C', 7], 
    [2, 'C', 8], 
    [3, 'C', 9]],
    columns=['t', 'group', 'val'])

df = df.set_index('t')
moving_avg = df.groupby('group').rolling(2).mean()
```

`moving_avg` is now a new dataframe. Note that because I set the index to be `t` in the first part, it's handled correctly in the grouping and rolling averages:

```
         val
group t     
A     1  NaN
      2  1.5
      3  2.5
B     1  NaN
      2  4.5
      3  5.5
C     1  NaN
      2  7.5
      3  8.5
```

Comment: Notice that the reason why this works fast isn't because of the indexing, rather because you aren't using `apply` at all.

Comment: @gented I've reworded to be clearer. I didn't mean to imply that indexing makes it faster, just that indexing properly allows downstream operations to return the right result automatically.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Pandas is impressively well stocked!

Comment: @chthonicdaemon However, to give credit where credit is due, I have timed both ways and the index *does* make it twice as fast (at least for this example) :).